# Vim and YouCompleteMe troubles (PROTOCOL_TLS)

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-python-mode

I wanted to install YouCompleteMe plugin for vim - however failed miserably at every step of the way. The problem was I had to compile everything by hand (remote machine - no root): started with vim v8.0, then it turned out I needed to add python to this mix (3.5.3) and finally I could download Ycm. I had some troubles in the begining but when python started to click with vim I thought I'm almost there. Unfortunately I'm stuck at a error message I can't decipher or get to the bottom of: when I run vim i get the message "YouCompleteMe unavailable: PROTOCOL_TLS" - anyone knows what this could mean or where the problem lies?

All help would be greatly appreciated,
drinker

Edit: I checked vims' logs and the failure seem to come from this line:

```
File "~/py-353/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 135, in <module>
  PROTOCOL_SSLv23 = _SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_SSLv23 = _SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT
File "~/py-353/lib/python3.5/enum.py", line 274, in __getattr__
  raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: PROTOCOL_TLS
```

Still - no idea what that means...

Comment: This sounds like it may be a bug in YouCompleteMe. You may get a better response by [reporting a bug](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues).

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems installing vim and YouCompleteMe as well. You might want to try managing your installations with [Linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/).
Linuxbrew installs programs from source or tarballs, and manages all dependencies for you. It does not need root (some setting up the environment might require it though) and can install the needed libraries for you.

A note on installing YouCompleteMe:
Since YouCompleteMe is depending on Python being the same as the one vim was installed with, it is important that you first install Python (`brew install python`), then vim (`brew install vim`) and then run the make script in the YouCompleteMe directory (`~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/install.py`).
This means that if you update Python you have to `brew reinstall` their dependents again.